# Flask-admin. Ajax loading of added values in view

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have one-to-many relationship and i have a lot of phones showing in view. All phones for related item loaded instantly, so it's really big timeout. Is it posibble to load them with ajax, or pass limit to query?

form_ajax_refs is not my option. As i understood form_ajax_refs will pre-populate drop-downs when searching, but already added values still will loaded all together. I want some limit to view already added data as on the screenshot

[image]